# What is the process of creating an asp.net webforms website

Tags: asp.net

Hi I recently started to learn asp.net and I gotten to some confusion as to when exactly should I be creating the stylesheet.Because I mostly done client-side work and some basic PHP I am kind of confused at the process.For example when I recieve a PSD and have to turn it into a website/webapplication I usually follow this stepps:

1. convert PSD to HTML/CSS
2. add any necesary Javasscript/jQuery code
3. add any necesarry PHP code(usually this ment form validation)

This worked because I always new the tags I use and what Id and classes I set for them.In asp.net webforms I can not always be sure what the generated tags for the various controls will be and also I can not be sure of the ID because from what I saw asp.net generates a more complex ID to make sure that the the id is unique.Aldo there is a way to get the client ID I don't think this works in a css file. That leaves me with only knowing the class I set witch I believe from a writing clean HTML point of view is not always necesary to add in order to create style for the page.

So what I wanted to know is what is the process of created a website with asp.net webfoms?

When should I start writing the css for the website?

Comment: I mean when when in the project lifecycle should I start creating the stylesheet(css) for the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your projects.
If it's a small projects and you're alone on it, you can write your CSS while you're coding your ASP.Net pages.
If you're part of a team or bigger company, you may have different persons for each roles, or development workflows.

ASP.Net webform is not known for it's usefullness when it comes to CSS. But in the end, it's all HTML.

You can use the `ClientIDMode="Static"` property of every ASP.Net control if you really need complete control over your ID's.
But regarding to what kind of HTML is usually generated by ASP.Net webform, I see no problem of using solely the `CssClass` property.

Personaly, with ASP.Net, I prefer the workflow :

1. Business logic
2. ASP.Net pages and controls
3. CSS and design

Answer (score 5):

You could set the ClientID property on your controls to static. This will remove the asp.net naming convention that is appended to the end of your control ID property.

For example.

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the ClientID mode to render as you would like it:

http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx

The design cycle is similar. One caveat: you will be creating server-side code last and the final thing you do is add the validators because this makes basic testing simpler, esp. with long forms.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use inline tags to get the client ID:

For example:

```
<asp:textbox ID="txt_MyTextBox" runat="server" />
```

Will be rendered (for example) as:

```
<input type="text" id="page_someotherstuff_nextedctrl_txt_MyTextBox" />
```

So, how do you know?

In JavaScript, if you need to validate the element you can use:

```
document.getElementById("<%= txt_MyTextBox.ClientID %>");
```

This will write the client ID to the HTML part - In the code behind you can just reference the control by name.

The only time you'll have problems is trying to assign CSS by ID, by class it's just the same as before.

Form validation you shouldn't need to get your hands dirty with in ASP.NET, using the built in validators, e.g.:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_MyTextBox" ... />
```

You can add custom validators should you need bespoke functionality.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET provides a unified Web development model that includes the services necessary for you to build enterprise-class Web applications. While ASP.NET is largely syntax compatible with Active Server Pages (ASP), it provides a new programming model and infrastructure that allow you to create a powerful new class of applications. ASP.NET is part of the .NET Framework and allows you to take full advantage of the features of the common language runtime, such as type safety, inheritance, language interoperability, and versioning.

This section provides you with conceptual information about how ASP.NET works and procedural topics that show you how to write code that takes full advantage of the power of this new technology.